# jQuery: modify html tables by changing number of columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

What's the easiest way to modify the html tables on the page with jQuery/javascript so that:
it contains the same data but has only two rows.

This is what is needed:

*Table 1*

City   **State** Population **Mayor** Time zone

New York **New York**  8,405,837 **Bill de Blasio** UTC-5

Chicago **Illinois** 2,695,598 **Rahm Emanuel** UTC-6

Houston **Texas** 2,195,914 **Annise Parker** UTC-6

*Table 2*:

City   New York

**State** **New York**

Population 8,405,837

**Mayor** **Bill de Blasio**

Time zone UTC-5

City   Chicago

**State** **Illinois**

Population 2,695,598

**Mayor** **Rahm Emanuel**

Time zone UTC-6

City   Houston

**State** **Texas**

Population 2,195,914

**Mayor** **Annise Parker**

Time zone UTC-6

This is what I have as for now and will continue working on it. It transposes the table: http://jsfiddle.net/0cm611xv/

```
$(".other").click(function(){
    $("table").each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var newrows = [];
        $this.find("tr").each(function(){
            var i = 0;
            $(this).find("td").each(function(){
                i++;
                if(newrows[i] === undefined) { newrows[i] = $("<tr></tr>"); }
                newrows[i].append($(this));
            });
        });
        $this.find("tr").remove();
        $.each(newrows, function(){
            $this.append(this);
        });
    });
    return false;
});
```

However, I need to modify the table in another manner - as described above and:

1. **The table should switch to the previous state if the link clicked again.**
2. All id, class names and attributes should be preserved and follow the value. As result, nothing is changed for the table if clicked on the link twice.
3. The number of columns and rows in the tables could be any. **M x N** table should be converted to **2 x (M*(N-1))** table upon clicking the link and **2 x (M*(N-1))** should be converted back to **M x N** by clicking the link again.
4. It should be done for each table on the page upon clicking the link.

I can ignore asking the SO and try to do it on my own but I believe it will take a lot of time to make it work and one person won't be able to find all bugs.

However, I believe this is an interesting task and this practical task could be useful for anyone else.

Comment: Downvoter, please explain your vote. You don't like my question? I didn't google it? No efforts from my side? Poor explanation? No code provided, only jsfiddle?

Comment: Is it not doing what you require in you fiddle?

Comment: @Alex Thomas No, it only transposes the table. I need to modify it so it has two columns only as shown in the example with cities above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had a go at this, and got a working example. In my example it changes the `<table>` to a `<dl>` as this is more semantically correct for the new layout.

**jQuery**

```
flag=0;
oldState = '';
$(".other").click(function(){
    myDls = '';
    if (flag == 0) {

        // Clone the old table
        oldState = $('#MyTable').clone(true);

        // Change Table to dl,dt,dd
        $('#MyTable tr').each(function(index){
            // Itterate through the <td>s
            $('td',this).each(function(index){
                // Get the <th> for the current <td> column and change to <dt>
                $(this).parent().parent().find('tr:first-child th:eq('+index+')').each(function(){
                    var replacementTagd = 'dt';
                    var outer = this.outerHTML;
                    var regex = new RegExp('<' + this.tagName, 'i');
                    newTagd = outer.replace(regex, '<' + replacementTagd);
                    regex = new RegExp('</' + this.tagName, 'i');
                    newTagd = newTagd.replace(regex, '</' + replacementTagd);
                });

                // Change <td> to <dd>
                var replacementTag = 'dd';
                var outer = this.outerHTML;
                var regex = new RegExp('<' + this.tagName, 'i');
                var newTag = outer.replace(regex, '<' + replacementTag);
                regex = new RegExp('</' + this.tagName, 'i');
                newTag = newTag.replace(regex, '</' + replacementTag);

                // Append to variable
                myDls += newTagd+newTag;
            });
        })

        $('#MyTable').replaceWith('<dl id="MyDl">'+myDls+'</dl>');
        flag=1;       
    }
    else {
        $('#MyDl').replaceWith(oldState);
        flag=0;
    }
});
```

Check out the jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/L8z9bsv0/

Answer (score 0):

Alex, thank you for your solution.
This is my solution (still in the middle, works for values and doesn't go back to the previous state yet):

```
$(".other").click(function(){

       $("table").each(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            var newrows = [];
            var firstRow = $this.first("tr");
            var rowsNum = firstRow.find("th").length;
            var colNum = $this.find("tr").length;

            //populate the first column
            var j;
            for (j=0; j< (colNum-1)*rowsNum; j++){
                newrows[j] = $("<tr></tr>");
                //newrows[j].append("<td>"+firstRow.find("th").eq(j%rowsNum).text()+"</td>");
                newrows[j].append(firstRow.find("th").eq(j%rowsNum)[0].outerHTML);
            }

            var i = 0;
            $this.find("tr:not(:first)").each(function(){
                $(this).find("td").each(function(){
                    //newrows[i].append("<td>"+$(this).text()+"</td>");
                    newrows[i].append($(this)[0].outerHTML);
                    i++;
                });
            });

            $this.find("tr").remove();
            $.each(newrows, function(){
                $this.append(this);
            });
        });
        return false;
```

});

Comment: This solution wont keep the attributes.

Comment: @Alex Thomas, you're right. I mentioned it above - works for values. But now, I updated that two strings (the old one are commented). Now it preserves the attributes.  However, it still has no revert operation and it might be more complicated.

Comment: @Alex Thomas Absolutely nothing. I didn't find any issues. Works like a charm. Will accept your answer as best in an hour or so I give a chance for other users to add more answers (if any). You've made my day. Thank you so much.